# Getting the key from a json file with subkey value

Tags: javascript, json

Can someone tell me how to get the main_key of a json file using sub_key values.. for example

```
{
  "a": {
    "category": "Drama"
  },
  "b": {
    "category": "Adventure",
  },
  "c": {
    "category": "Drama"
  }
}
```

So i want to retrieve all the main keys contains 'Drama' as value of category.

Can You explain the functions in easy wat as u help.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key / value pairs then [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) that to an array of keys by checking the `category` property of each value

```js
const obj = {"a":{"category":"Drama"},"b":{"category":"Adventure"},"c":{"category":"Drama"}};

const dramaKeys = Object.entries(obj).reduce((keys, [key, { category }]) => {
  if (category === "Drama") {
    keys.push(key);
  }
  return keys;
}, []);

console.log(dramaKeys);
```

---

You could also use a *filter* and *map* for the same effect

```js
const dramaKeys = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([, { category }]) => category === "Drama")
  .map(([key]) => key);
```